# check if data is served from RAM and not from secondary storage

Tags: solr, ram

I have few solr indices. They are being saved on my secondary storage (i can see the index files). I want to know whether while querying, whether the indices are served from RAM (main memory) or from secondary memory.

How can I check it? The idea would be, if the indices are served from secondary memory, can I do some disk I/O delay so that overall query time is increased because in case of RAM serving indices, this won't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

look at http://your.host:8983/solr/core0/admin/stats.jsp (this url is for multicore) and see at the Cache section